# how to include bootstrap in a node-express project

Tags: jquery, css, node.js, express, bootstrap-4

the following code comes from [code author](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9np39a6N8ng). Basically it is a bootstrap/css project which i want to connect to backend. However, I can't find a way to render the bootstrap with the following code:

file form:

- fileName

  - node_modules
  - routes

    - public.js
  - views

    - publicAssets

      - css
      - js
      - img
    - public.ejs
  - app.js

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port=4000;
const publicRouter = require('./routes/public');
const path = require('path');

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`listening to port ${port}`);
});


app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));


    


app.use('/',publicRouter);
```

public.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>WebSite Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="publicAssets/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="wrapper">
       

        <header>
        
        
            <div class="top-bar">

                <div class="row">
                    
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 d-flex breaking-news-bar">
                        <div class="breaking-title"><h6>Trending</h6></div>
                        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded breaking">
                            <div class="owl-stage-outer">
                                <div class="owl-stage">
                                    <div class="owl-item b-news-item"><a href="#">01.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></div>
                                    <div class="owl-item b-news-item"><a href="#">02.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></div>
                                    <div class="owl-item b-news-item"><a href="#">03.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></div>
                                    <div class="owl-item b-news-item"><a href="#">03.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="owl-nav">
                                <div class="owl-prev">
                                    <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="owl-next">
                                        <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End breaking news -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
       
       


        </header>
    </div>


    <script src="publicAssets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="publicAssets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="publicAssets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="publicAssets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css works fine however i can't use bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

There’re [several ways](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/) to include Bootstrap but all of them come down to the missing stylesheet in the `<head>` element of your `public.ejs`.

Also when you include your scripts, `jquery-3.5.1.min.js` should be placed in front of `bootstrap.min.js` because Bootstrap 4 depends on jQuery.

**Method 1. Download and include all assets manually**

This seems to be what your tutorial tries to do.

1. Check that all assets are in place. If they are not, download them again. Your `publicAssets` folder should include at the bare minimum:

- publicAssets

  - css

    - styles.css
    - bootstrap.min.css
  - js

    - bootstrap.min.js
    - jquery-3.5.1.min.js

2. Add the stylesheet:

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="publicAssets/js/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
  ...
</head>
```

3. Change the scripts order:

```
  ...
  <script src="publicAssets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="publicAssets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  ...
</body>
```

*You should probably also download font-awesome as a local asset and use bundler like Webpack or Browserify when you are finished with development.*

**Method 2. Include it as a node module**

1. In command line type:

`npm i bootstrap@latest jquery@latest`

2. Add the stylesheet

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
  ...
</head>
```

3. Change your scripts to:

```
  ... 
  <script src="node_modules/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  ...
</body>
```

*Keep in mind that this method pretty much requires using some kind of bundler but you probably will want to do it anyway.*

**Method 3. Include all assets as a link from CDN**

Skip downloading assets altogether and use their web hosted versions:

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ... 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

include bootstrap and j Query by ruing  
`npm install bootstrap@latest jquery@latest`
or
`npm i bootstrap@latest jquery@latest`
Now check your static middleware path 
if `app.use(express.static(__dirname))` its mean you are in main directory
include simple by giving path like
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>`
 `<script src="./node_modules/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

if your path is in some folder like
if `app.use(express.static(__dirname, "some folder" ))` its mean you are in main directory
include simple by giving path like
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>`
 `<script src="../node_modules/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`
`Note:` make sure your server file or app file in main directry

Answer (score 0):

Just include the css bootstrap cdn inside your head tag:
`<head> <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">  </head>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Express, you may first add the following to your **app.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/")));
```

Thanks to `express.static()`, a built-in middleware function in Express to serve static files, you may now make use of Bootstrap in your HTML pages by linking to it as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
```